# Почему кнопка Google Sign-In не отображается в той самой строке?

Tags: bootstrap, opencart

На OpenCart в View логина добавил форму и div от Google

```html
 <form class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="submit" value="{{ button_login }}" class="btn btn-primary" />
     <div class="g-signin2" style="display: inline;" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с обычной Bootstrap кнопкой все нормально в одной строке. Почему?

Answer (score 2):

div.g-signin2 не Бутстрап-кнопка и приходит со своими css-свойствами. Просто переопределите их в своём style.css

Comment: ok, а где взять css-свойства google кнопки?

Comment: посмотреть в devtools браузера.

Comment: изменил код добавив в стиль display: inline; (смотрите код в вопросе) так как там везде display: block; но ничего не произошло, подозреваю из-за дивов внутри, но как им переопределить свойство?

Comment: ссыль на сайт оставьте в вопросе

Comment: пока localhost.. знаю что google работать не будет, вопрос чисто дизайна

Comment: @MikeWaters может этот блок обернуть в блок и его стилизовать?

Comment: захостите сайт чтобы можно было посмотреть (на крайняк откройте с локал в мир) сервисам гугл, на сколько помню, надо чтобы домен был не local, а что хост локал им не важно. работать будет - снените домен для этого сайта.